# CTE result not visible within CTE CASE WHEN

Tags: case, common-table-expression

I'm working in MySQL sandbox environment and getting runtime error: Unknown column 'tab.maxid' in 'field list'.
Here is my original code:

```
with tab as(
select max(id) as maxid from seat)
select id,
CASE
    WHEN (id % 2 <> 0 and id = tab.maxid) THEN student
    WHEN (id % 2 <> 0 and id < tab.maxid) THEN lead(student) over(order by id)
    ELSE lag(student) over(order by id)
END AS `student`
from seat;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
;with tab as(
select max(id) as maxid from seat
)
select id,
CASE
    WHEN (id % 2 <> 0 and id = (select maxid from tab)) THEN student
    WHEN (id % 2 <> 0 and id < (select maxid from tab)) THEN lead(student) over(order by id)
    ELSE lag(student) over(order by id)
END AS `student`
from seat;
```

the other option is:

```
select id,
CASE
    WHEN (id % 2 <> 0 and id = (select max(id) from seat)) THEN student
    WHEN (id % 2 <> 0 and id < (select max(id) from seat)) THEN lead(student) over(order by id)
    ELSE lag(student) over(order by id)
END AS `student`
from seat;
```

Comment: Yes, I used subquery and it worked, thank you! But why tab.maxid isn't working?

Comment: @Olexiy Usov how not working?! already in your subquery you are calling the CTE.

Comment: @Olexiy Usov if you remove the CTE then your subquery will not work

Comment: @Olexiy Usov the problem in your original code was that you defined the CTE but did not call it

Comment: @Olexiy Usov So you used the code I posted exactly. Yes?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my comment. Yes your code works!

Comment: @Olexiy Usov great! happy for that, you may like to mark my post as an accepted answer?! thanks